# What is meant by "one art stroke at a time" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in an [article](https://www.pressreader.com/india/the-hindu/20190530/282720523444765) in "The Hindu" which was:

> Whatever the story may be, the psychedelic images that spells joy and positivity are a living testament to the power of one man and his mission to save his home one art stroke at a time.

What does the last part of sentence mean? And, shouldn't there be a preposition before "one art stroke"?

Comment: Possibly a comma. It means "step by step" or in this case "brushstroke by brushstroke".

Comment: It's not a very well written sentence. The word "spells" should be "spell" and images are not a "living testament".